# Javascript: in ff in history object custom function disappears

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have strange situation in ff. I added custom function to history object and after some time it disappears. Is that some kind of ff protection of default objects or what? Maybe when new state added to history it kills my function?

All other browsers is ok.

PS
I can use some custom object instead of history, but I want to know whats wrong with history object

Comment: what kind of history object ? can you show us your codes ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I understood it is `window.history` provided by the browser

Comment: however example code would still be beneficial. are you using history.pushState() or other methods?

Comment: @redexp I thing you have move to other page and new page load new DOM this is why your function removed.

Comment: @F1betaIndia nope I'm not reloaded my page

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the specific `FireFox` implementation of history I can tell you that if you modify it and it returns to default state then the browser much be resetting it under a certain condition. Don't use history for custom implementations is my suggestion.

Comment: @redexp I guess because they aren't resetting it?